# Is a check for isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class] sufficient for plist safety?

Tags: objective-c, plist

I'm trying to check that a value can be safely added to a plist. I've read [Apple's documentation on plists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html).

I'm storing values in an `NSMutableDictionary` and then serializing them using `NSPropertyListSerialization`. If I want to check that a value added to my dictionary will be serializable, can I use `[value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]` or do I need to check against the core foundation types backing it?

Comment: That sounds like what I would do in your position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's safe enough. But did you know that you can write plists by simply doing:

```
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

As long as you only have plist compatible objects in the dictionary of course.

Comment: A confidence builder AND a great tip. Thanks!